# Access URL parameters in django 1.7 template without using context processors

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

`http://www.example.com/soe/?param1=val1`

this is current url and I want to access variable {{param1}} in django template. (Django 1.7)

I know there are already many threads available for this problem but all of them are using ContextProcessor.(or render_to_response)

I'm simply using `return render(request, template, {})` and dont want to use ContextProcessors.

One way to solve this problem is I pass the value of param1 when rendering, I mean

`return render(request, template, {'param1': request.GET.get('param1')})`

but I'm just wondering If I can access this variable in template itself? because there might be 10 parameters.

Comment: What, exactly, do you have against context processors? They are the perfect solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following *will* actually work...

```
{{ request.GET.param1 }}
```

... as long as you have the default `django.template.context_processors.request` enabled in your settings file.

```
DJANGO_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ...any other context processors you want to run
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

All this it does is place the request object in your template context, which you can then use to access url parameters.  It's exactly the functionality you're looking for.  See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request).

Your only other option is to pass the parameter to the template explicitly, as you describe in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using custom tags in django templates.

Comment: could you please elaborate. creating a template tag is again something I want to avoid if I can get in template itself.

Comment: see if this helps {{ request.GET.param1 }}

Comment: c'mon! first thing I tried was this. even {{GET.param1}} because we can access {{user}} without using {{request.user}}. not working

Comment: gautam's suggestion does work as long as you have `django.template.context_processors.request` enabled in your django settings.